# Reading video metadata on iOS 7 - always empty

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, alassetslibrary

I am exporting a Quicktime video using AVExporterSession and setting the metadata on it as follows:

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *newMetaDataCommentItem = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
[newMetaDataCommentItem setKeySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeMetadata];
[newMetaDataCommentItem setKey:AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKeyComment];
[newMetaDataCommentItem setValue:@"Test metadata value"];

NSMutableArray *metaData = [NSMutableArray array];
[metaData addObject:newMetaDataCommentItem];

exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mutableComposition
                                            presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=[[SNMovieManager instance] urlForFinalMovie];
exporter.metadata = metaData;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = video;
```

I then import the file video to my Mac and run mdls on it and see the value has been set correctly: `kMDItemComment = "Test metadata value"`

The bit I can't do is read that value back. I am using the following to read the file. The asset is correct but the metadata property is always an empty dictionary.

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if([[result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyType"] isEqualToString:@"ALAssetTypeVideo"])
            {
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = result.defaultRepresentation;
                NSDictionary *metadata = rep.metadata;
               [images addObject:(id)rep.fullScreenImage];
            }
```

Does anyone know if I am taking the correct approach here and if not let me know what the correct approach to read this comment back out is?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I would be highly appreciated if you can provide more code base related to the PhotoLibrary save process.

Otherwise only one answer, Metadata will return `nil` if the representation is one that the system cannot **interpret**.

The returned dictionary holds the properties of the video at a specified location in an file source.

Answer (score 0):

I'think your problem is on getting metadata script
You should get an AVURLAsset first and get metadata from it ALAssetRepresentation metadata is different

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if([[result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyType"] isEqualToString:@"ALAssetTypeVideo"])
        {
            AVURLAsset *videoAset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[[asset defaultRepresentation] url]];
                if ([[videoAset metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatQuickTimeMetadata] count]) {
                    AVMutableMetadataItem *meta = [[videoAset metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatQuickTimeUserData] objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSLog(@"%@",meta);
                    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[[videoAset metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatQuickTimeMetadata] count]);
                }

        }
```